# Why was Spike looking for beans in "Cowboy Bebop: The Movie"?

Tags: cowboy-bebop

In *Cowboy Bebop: The Movie* how did Spike know where to look for the virus? 
How did he end up in that Moroccan styled market?

Do we see him getting any leads that lead him there?